# How to make CheckBox focus border appear when calling CheckBox.Focus()?

Tags: wpf, checkbox, focus, border, indicator

When the user tabs into a CheckBox to give it focus, a dotted border appears around the CheckBox to indicate that it has focus.

When the CheckBox gets focused by code calling `myCheckBox.Focus()`, no such indicator appears (even though pressing the space bar toggles the state).

How can I make the CheckBox focus border appear when I have programmatically focused the CheckBox?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The border is intentionally only shown if you are navigating by the keyboard (Tab key). The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613567.aspx) on this topic has further details:

> *Focus visual styles act only when the
>   focus action was initiated by the
>   keyboard. Any mouse action or
>   programmatic focus change disables the
>   mode for focus visual styles.*

If you want to show a border, you could use a Trigger on the IsFocused- Property to do some visual changes (although you can't set the border with this) or if you actually want a border, you would have to create your own ControlTemplate.

There is also a [thread here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238790/wpf-how-to-programmatically-give-visual-feedback-that-the-keyboard-focus-is-in-a) on a somewhat related topic where the suggestion is to simulate a key press, but I would suggest not to use this solution for your problem.

Comment: How to visually show which button is the default button on a dialog without having to mess with styles then?

Answer (score 2):

By editing the [`KeyboardNavigationEx`](https://github.com/ControlzEx/ControlzEx/blob/develop/src/ControlzEx/KeyboardNavigationEx.cs) file from [ControlzEx](https://github.com/ControlzEx/ControlzEx) I managed to solve the issue (full credit goes, as always, to [punker76](https://github.com/punker76)).

Just call the `KeyboardHelper.Focus` method passing the `UIElement` that shoud be focused (e.g. `KeyboardHelper.Focus(myCheckBox)`)

Here's the `KeyboardHelper` class:

```
public sealed class KeyboardHelper
{
    private static KeyboardHelper _Instance;

    private readonly PropertyInfo _AlwaysShowFocusVisual;
    private readonly MethodInfo _ShowFocusVisual;

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static KeyboardHelper()
    {
    }

    private KeyboardHelper()
    {
        var type = typeof(KeyboardNavigation);

        _AlwaysShowFocusVisual = type.GetProperty("AlwaysShowFocusVisual", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
        _ShowFocusVisual = type.GetMethod("ShowFocusVisual", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
    }

    internal static KeyboardHelper Instance => _Instance ?? (_Instance = new KeyboardHelper());

    internal void ShowFocusVisualInternal()
    {
        _ShowFocusVisual.Invoke(null, null);
    }

    internal bool AlwaysShowFocusVisualInternal
    {
        get { return (bool)_AlwaysShowFocusVisual.GetValue(null, null); }
        set { _AlwaysShowFocusVisual.SetValue(null, value, null); }
    }

    public static void Focus(UIElement element)
    {
        element?.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
        {
            var keybHack = KeyboardHelper.Instance;
            var oldValue = keybHack.AlwaysShowFocusVisualInternal;

            keybHack.AlwaysShowFocusVisualInternal = true;

            try
            {
                Keyboard.Focus(element);
                keybHack.ShowFocusVisualInternal();
            }
            finally
            {
               keybHack.AlwaysShowFocusVisualInternal = oldValue;
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'initially set chkCheckBox.Appearance = 1

'on Got Focus set appearance = 0 - Flat
Private Sub chkCheckBox_GotFocus()
  chkCheckBox.Appearance = 0
End Sub

'on Lost Focus set appearance = 1 - 3D
Private Sub chkCheckBox_LostFocus()
  chkCheckBox.Appearance = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: CheckBox in WPF doesn't have an `Appearance` property.  Is this answer for WinForms?