# How do I cancel input focus change?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication

In a WPF application I want to implemement authentication logic: Only if a user is logged in he should be able to edit a certain textbox i a dialog box.

What I want is the following behavior:

1. If the user is logged in, he can click the text box and start
   editing its contents just as usual.
2. If the user is not logged in, he should still be able to click the text box, but he should then be prompted whith the login-dialog. After having completed the
   login-dialog, he should find himself back in the textbox, now in
   edit mode.
3. If the user cancels the login-dialog (without logging in), the input focus should move to
   the Cancel button of the dialog that contains the text box, thus
   preventing him from editing the textbox's contents.

I have tried hooking into the PreviewGotKeyboardFocus event this way:

```
    private void TextBox_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool loggedIn = ExecuteLogin(); //shows the login dialog and returns new login status

        if (!loggedIn)
        {
            CancelButton.Focus();
             e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

It does indeed work fine as long as the user completes the login procedure, but if he cancels the login dialog instead, it does not transfer the input focus to the cancel button. Further the event handler is called multiple times (once for each text box in my dialog), and the whole system seems to be messed up (the application's process does not terminate when the application is closed - it must be killed afterwards).

What should I change to obtain the behavior I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following sample code works as expected for me. Click on the TextBox in the middle, answer "No" in the dialog and press [enter].

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private bool _handleEvent = true;
    private void TextBox_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!_handleEvent)
            return;

        bool loggedIn = ExecuteLogin(); //shows the login dialog and returns new login status

        if (!loggedIn)
        {
            CancelButton.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;

        }
    }

    public bool ExecuteLogin() => MessageBox.Show("Login?", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes;

    private void CancelButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("click");
    }
}
```

---

```
<StackPanel>

    <TextBox  />
    <TextBox PreviewGotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" />
    <TextBox />

    <Button x:Name="CancelButton" Content="Cancel" Click="CancelButton_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

Note that the dotted focus border is intentionally only shown if you are navigating to the Button by using the keyboard:

[WPF Button to have Keyboard focus (dotted border around) during the startup or activation of window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468419/wpf-button-to-have-keyboard-focus-dotted-border-around-during-the-startup-or-a)

Comment: Thank you very much for your fine answer. I used your code example, and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `GotFocus` event.

Instead of always open the dialog and try to close it with code can't you get log information immediately, check if the user is logged and then open or not the dialog?