# how to create the blue border on checkbox when mouse is over the containing element C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, wpf-controls

I have a `WrapPanel` containing a `Label` and a `CheckBox`. The idea is to make the Label and the CheckBox look like 1 element, so when the `WrapPanel`'s `MouseLeftButtonUp` is fired (weather the event happens on the CheckBox, or the Label), the checkbox inside it becomes checked (or unchecked if it was already checked).

In WPF, when you move your mouse over a CheckBox it gets this blue border. i want it to happen when the mouse goes over any part of the WrapPanel (the Label or the CheckBox itself)

I tried to call the `myCheckbox.Focus();` when the `MouseEnter` for the WrapPanel is fired, but didn't do the trick.

I also saw this link on [how to make checkbox focus border apear when calling CheckBox.Focus()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400570/how-to-make-checkbox-focus-border-appear-when-calling-checkbox-focus), but it didn't answer my question either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the template of the `CheckBox` to use a `WrapPanel` instead of the default `Grid`:

```
<CheckBox>
    <TextBlock>Label that wraps with the CheckBox...</TextBlock>
    <CheckBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="2" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
                    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" StrokeDashArray="1 2" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" StrokeThickness="1"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                        <WrapPanel x:Name="templateRoot" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="1" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                    <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="2" Opacity="0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                                <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                                <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </CheckBox.Style>
</CheckBox>
```

Comment: I'm really and truly a beginner to wpf (and programming in general, for that matter). any chance you can explain what happens with this code? (just give me a general idea, or recommend a resource for me to learn this stuff by. I'd really appreciate it♥)

Comment: I'm mean, is the `wrappanel` a child element now? why do you define an element in the `Setter.Value` section??

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to an alternative (simpler) solution, This is how you should do it: define a custom style for the checkbox and override the Template so to get the WrapPanel and whatever controls you want look as part of the CheckBox..

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" x:Key="myCheckboxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                <WrapPanel>
                    <Label />
                    <!-- other Controls -->
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Apply the custom style to the checkbox

```
<CheckBox Style="{StaticResource myCheckboxStyle}" Content="Check Me"/>
```